# flex wrapping - remove empty space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've created a div container, which includes some checkboxes. (In the code snippet are only the labels included). I set the display to inline flex and wrap. The max width of the container is 300px. The container gets an empty space on the right (the width depends on the items of the flex box) when the items get wrapped. How can you remove this space? So the container fits the wrapped content.

[empty space in flex container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkqJF.png)

```css
.module-group {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  max-width: 300px;
  gap: .5rem;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.btn-test {
  color: #0d6efd;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #0d6efd;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<h5>Test</h5>
<div class="module-group">
  <label class="btn-test" for="aaaaaa">aaaaaa</label>

  <label class="btn-test" for="bbbbbbbb">bbbbbbbb</label>

  <label class="btn-test" for="cccc">cccc</label>

  <label class="btn-test" for="uuid">ddddddddd</label>

  <label class="btn-test" for="eeeeee">eeeeee</label>

  <label class="btn-test" for="fff">fff</label>

  <label class="btn-test" for="ggggggggg">ggggggggg</label>

  <label class="btn-test" for="hhhhhh">hhhhhh</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot remove it

Answer (score 1):

easiest solution would be the use of `flex-grow`:

```css
.module-group {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;

    max-width: 300px;
    gap: .5rem;
    padding: .5rem;

}

.btn-test {
    flex-grow: 1;
    color: #0d6efd;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #0d6efd;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

}
```

```html
<h5>Test</h5>
        <div class="module-group">
            <label class="btn-test" for="aaaaaa">aaaaaa</label>

            <label class="btn-test" for="bbbbbbbb">bbbbbbbb</label>

            <label class="btn-test" for="cccc">cccc</label>

            <label class="btn-test" for="uuid">ddddddddd</label>

            <label class="btn-test" for="eeeeee">eeeeee</label>

            <label class="btn-test" for="fff">fff</label>

            <label class="btn-test" for="ggggggggg">ggggggggg</label>

            <label class="btn-test" for="hhhhhh">hhhhhh</label>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is there a way without changeing the size of the btn-test elements?

Comment: not any clean solution. you can resize the container down, but theat would require for the buttons to exactly fill the space which will be pretty much impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex: 1;` to `btn-test`.

```css
.module-group {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  max-width: 300px;
  gap: .5rem;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.btn-test {
  color: #0d6efd;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  flex: 1;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #0d6efd;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<h5>Test</h5>
<div class="module-group">
  <label class="btn-test" for="aaaaaa">aaaaaa</label>
  <label class="btn-test" for="bbbbbbbb">bbbbbbbb</label>
  <label class="btn-test" for="cccc">cccc</label>
  <label class="btn-test" for="uuid">ddddddddd</label>
  <label class="btn-test" for="eeeeee">eeeeee</label>
  <label class="btn-test" for="fff">fff</label>
  <label class="btn-test" for="ggggggggg">ggggggggg</label>
  <label class="btn-test" for="hhhhhh">hhhhhh</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way without changeing the size of the btn-test elements?

Comment: @TimMatten `margin: auto;` on `btn-test` but then there won't really be any growing / shrinking going on. You can also use `justify-content: center;` on `.module-group`. Can see that [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l5o2.png)